# How do you query the set of Users in Google App Domain within your Google App Engine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps, gql, gqlquery

If you have a Google App Engine project you can authenticate based on either a) anyone with a google account or b) a particular google app domain. Since you can connect these two entities I would assume there is some way to query the list of users that can be authenticated. The use case is outputting a roster of all members in an organization to a web page running on Google App Engine. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Querying all users that could possibly authenticate in the case of 'a' (all gmail users) would be millions and millions users, so I'm sure you don't expect to do that.

I'm sure you actually mean query the ones who have logged into your application previously, in which case you just create a table to store their user information, and populate that whenever an authenticated user is on your site.

You can read more in the Google App Engine Docs under [Using User Values With the Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/users/userobjects.html)

Comment: You have the option of authenticated on either the google user base (gmail users) OR the user base of a Google App instance (http://www.google.com/a/). I was hoping I could query the latter

Comment: storing authenticated users addresses either case, but you can't ever query information about users who have never authenticated from google-app-engine (GAE) as Archnid pointed out. A complete list of google apps users would come from the google apps interface, not GAE.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to App Engine to do this. If you have Apps Premium edition, however, you can use the [reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the Premium (or Education) Google apps version, and you can use the api to list all users in the apps domain:

`GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/user/2.0`

see docs here:

http://code.google.com/apis/apps/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's no way to get information about people who haven't logged into your application.